# Semantic UI - grid and flex - horizontal scrollbar appears when vertical scrollbar appears

Tags: html, css, flexbox, semantic-ui

I have a two-column grid using Semantic UI.

```
<div id="grid" class="ui two column grid">
  <div class="twelve wide column">...</div>
  <div class="four wide column">...</div>
</div>
```

This grid is inside a fixed-header, fixed-footer flex container:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="grid"...         <---here goes the previous grid
  </div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

Using minimal flex CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#header, #footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

#content{
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that when the content is long enough, the vertical scrollbar appears in the `#content` div. This in turn makes the `#content` div slightly narrower, which then causes a horizontal bar to appear in the same div.

How to prevent this horizontal bar from appearing?

[image]

Comment: Try giving the `#content` `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks @HaoWu . That solves it, but removes the possibility of any horizontal scrolling, ie: when the window is resized so small that the columns stop fitting then the scrollbar does have a purpose. In normal screen there should be no scroll because that's the point of having two columns with 12 and 4 wide, right? But still I feel that something is off if I'm hiding the horizontal scrollbar. It should not be there, instead of there but hidden. Maybe its something wrong with semantic UI because it uses negative margins.